# Fetching Python news headlines for Alexa

Tags: python, web-scraping, flask

I've recently added a custom [Alexa Flask Briefing skill](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/understanding-the-flash-briefing-skill-api) that calls an API endpoint which scrapes top news headlines from the [Planet Python RSS feed](http://planetpython.org/).

It works - whenever you ask Alexa about the news, it's gonna read top 5 (flash briefing API's limitation) topics from the Planet Python section. But, I'd like to see if there are things to improve in the code:

```
import logging

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
from dateutil.parser import parse
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from nltk import sent_tokenize
import requests


PLANET_PYTHON_FEED_URL = "http://planetpython.org/rss20.xml"

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def main():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
        }

        response = session.get(PLANET_PYTHON_FEED_URL)
        data = response.content

        root = etree.fromstring(data)

        return jsonify([
            {
                "uid": topic.findtext("guid"),
                "updateDate": parse(topic.findtext("pubDate")).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"),  # "2016-04-10T00:00:00.0Z"
                "titleText": topic.findtext("title"),
                "mainText": sent_tokenize(BeautifulSoup(topic.findtext("description"), "lxml").text)[0],
                "redirectionUrl": topic.findtext("link")
            }
            for topic in root.xpath("/rss/channel/item")
        ])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

Note that, since there is a news description length limitation, I had to tokenize the descriptions and cut the first sentences only for the Alexa to read - for that, I've used `sent_tokenize` from `nltk` - not sure, if this is an overkill for such a straightforward problem.

Project is also [available on github](https://github.com/alecxe/PlanetPythonSkill), hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You probably want to move the session to a global variable(or simply use `requests.get`) else at function level it is not helping in re-using any connections right now and is adding an extra level of indentation to your code.
- This is mostly opinionated but grouping `from x import y` based imports below `import z` makes the imports bit easier to read. Plus keep the items within each group sorted as well.  Google's style guide also contains a [related example](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Imports_formatting#Imports_formatting).

  ```
  import requests
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  from dateutil.parser import parse
  from flask import Flask, jsonify
  from lxml import etree
  from nltk import sent_tokenize
  ```